# Not able to establish connection through Airtel 3G USB Dongle after its detected as modem

Tags: 16.04, usb-modem

I have been able to use the same dongle to connect on Fedora 23 and connect and browse the internet. The dongle model is Huawei E1731

On ubuntu 16.04 I'm unable to establish connection even though the USB dongle is detected. Through `lsusb` I get the following result

```
ID 12d1:1446 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. Broadband stick (modem on)
```

Through `nmcli con` the output is

```
Airtel01                 5942e4c0-80c0-4f6b-825e-8e8b41185266  gsm              --
```

When dialing through `sudo wvdial` the output is

```
sudo wvdial
--> WvDial: Internet dialer version 1.61
--> Cannot open /dev/ttyUSB0: No such file or directory
--> Cannot open /dev/ttyUSB0: No such file or directory
--> Cannot open /dev/ttyUSB0: No such file or directory
```

and it fails to connect.

my `wvdial.conf` contents are

```
[Dialer Defaults]
        Modem = /dev/ttyUSB0
        ISDN = 0
        Modem Type = Analog Modem
        Baud = 460800
        Init1 = ATX3
        Init2 = AT&F Q0 V1 E0 S0=0 &C1 &D2 +FCLASS=0
        Init3 = at+cgdcont=1,"IP","airtelgprs.com"
        Phone = *99#
        Dial Attempts = 5
        Stupid Mode = on
        Dial Command = ATDT
        Idle Seconds = 7200
        Ask Passwords = 0
        Password = { }
        Username = { }
        Carrier Check = on
        New PPPD = 1
        Auto DNS = on
```

I have tried to switch to modem mode. the output from the command `cat /etc/usb_modeswitch.d/12d1\:1446` is

```
Huawei E173s

DefaultVendor= 0x12d1
DefaultProduct= 0x1c0b

TargetVendor= 0x12d1
TargetProduct= 0x1c05

CheckSuccess=20

MessageEndpoint= 0x0f
MessageContent= "55534243123456780000000000000011062000000100000000000000000000"
```